# How to extend the scraping done to more than 1st page using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

Hi I was going through a Python code (pasted below). The code is working fine for scraping the 1st page results (25 listing per page). However, I would want to extend its usability to scrape results from atleast 10 more pages

For example I want to generate results for zip code - 98021 which has 80 listings in total (until page 4). However, when I run the code below using `python zillow.py 980021 newest`, it displays only 25 listings

Since I am a newbie in python I request you to please help me out with this objective.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import unicodecsv as csv
import argparse

def parse(zipcode,filter=None):

if filter=="newest":
    url = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/{0}/0_singlestory/days_sort".format(zipcode)
elif filter == "cheapest":
    url = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/{0}/0_singlestory/pricea_sort/".format(zipcode)
else:
    url = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/{0}_rb/?fromHomePage=true&shouldFireSellPageImplicitClaimGA=false&fromHomePageTab=buy".format(zipcode)

for i in range(10):
    # try:
    headers= {
                'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
                'accept-language':'en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,ml;q=0.4',
                'cache-control':'max-age=0',
                'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
                'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    parser = html.fromstring(response.text)
    search_results = parser.xpath("//div[@id='search-results']//article")
    properties_list = []

    for properties in search_results:
        raw_address = properties.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='address']//span[@itemprop='streetAddress']//text()")
        raw_city = properties.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='address']//span[@itemprop='addressLocality']//text()")
        raw_state= properties.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='address']//span[@itemprop='addressRegion']//text()")
        raw_postal_code= properties.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='address']//span[@itemprop='postalCode']//text()")
        raw_price = properties.xpath(".//span[@class='zsg-photo-card-price']//text()")
        raw_info = properties.xpath(".//span[@class='zsg-photo-card-info']//text()")
        raw_broker_name = properties.xpath(".//span[@class='zsg-photo-card-broker-name']//text()")
        url = properties.xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'overlay-link')]/@href")
        raw_title = properties.xpath(".//h4//text()")

        address = ' '.join(' '.join(raw_address).split()) if raw_address else None
        city = ''.join(raw_city).strip() if raw_city else None
        state = ''.join(raw_state).strip() if raw_state else None
        postal_code = ''.join(raw_postal_code).strip() if raw_postal_code else None
        price = ''.join(raw_price).strip() if raw_price else None
        info = ' '.join(' '.join(raw_info).split()).replace(u"\xb7",',')
        broker = ''.join(raw_broker_name).strip() if raw_broker_name else None
        title = ''.join(raw_title) if raw_title else None
        property_url = "https://www.zillow.com"+url[0] if url else None 
        is_forsale = properties.xpath('.//span[@class="zsg-icon-for-sale"]')
        properties = {
                        'address':address,
                        'city':city,
                        'state':state,
                        'postal_code':postal_code,
                        'price':price,
                        'facts and features':info,
                        'real estate provider':broker,
                        'url':property_url,
                        'title':title
        }
        if is_forsale:
            properties_list.append(properties)
    return properties_list
    # except:
    #   print ("Failed to process the page",url)

if __name__=="__main__":
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
argparser.add_argument('zipcode',help = '')
sortorder_help = """
available sort orders are :
newest : Latest property details,
cheapest : Properties with cheapest price
"""
argparser.add_argument('sort',nargs='?',help = sortorder_help,default ='Homes For You')
args = argparser.parse_args()
zipcode = args.zipcode
sort = args.sort
print ("Fetching data for %s"%(zipcode))
scraped_data = parse(zipcode,sort)
print ("Writing data to output file")
with open("properties-%s.csv"%(zipcode),'wb')as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['title','address','city','state','postal_code','price','facts and features','real estate provider','url']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in  scraped_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the link to the next page from the current page and then update the url that you use to scrape from.

Here's a rough example of how that could work:

```
def parse(zipcode, url, filter=None):
    # get results how you are
    # get url from next page button
    return results, next_page_url

full_results = []
results, next_page_url = parse(zipcode, initial_page_url, filter=filter)

full_results += results

while (len(results) >= 25 and next_page_url):
    results, next_page_url = parse(zipcode, next_page_url, filter=filter)
    full_results += results
```

So in this example `parse` takes the url to scrape from as a second positional argument and returns the results and the url for the next page to scrape.

This will just keep scraping as long as there are the max results (25) on the page and a url to the next page is returned.